When combining iteration and recursion, how do I express the recursion via tail calls?
I am working on a practice problem and I have found a recursive solution. However, I can't figure out how to express the solution as tail recursion.
I think that the issue that I am having can be generalized to:

At a given recursive step, I need to iterate over the options that I
have at the current step.
In order to explore a given option, I need to recurse on that option.
How do I express the recursion as tail conversion, given that once it returns I need to check whether I have found the solution or whether I need to explore the next option.

Problem:
Given a target and a list of scores, write a function which returns a list of scores (represented by their indexes in the list of scores) which sum to the target.
Solution in Pseudocode:
Function, findScoresThatReachTarget(target, scores):
    scoreIndexes = range(0, scores.length);
    return generateScores([])

Note: Assume that generateCombos has closure scope to target, scores, and scoreIndexes
Function, generateCombos(currentCombo):
    Iterate through the scores that are not already in the combo:
        newCombo = [...currentCombo, currentScore]
        if score of the newCombo is greater than target:
            Start the next iteration
        if score of the newCombo equals the target:
            Return the solution
        else
            potentialSolution = generateCombo(newCombo)
            if potentialSolution
                Return the solution
            else
                Start the next iteration

Solution in Javascript:
const _ = require('lodash');

function findScoresThatReachTarget(target, scores) {
    const scoreIndexes = _.range(0, scores.length);
    return generateCombos([]);


    function generateCombos(currentCombo) {
        const newScoreIndexes = _.difference(scoreIndexes, currentCombo);
        return findResult(newFlavors, currentScoreIndex => {
            const newCombo = [...currentCombo, currentScoreIndex];
            const scoreOfNewCombo = calculateScoreOfCombo(newCombo);
            if (scoreOfNewCombo > target) {
                return; // Start next iteration
            } else if (scoreOfNewCombo === target) {
                return newCombo; // We found the solution
            } else {
                const potentialSolution = generateCombos(newCombo);
                if (potentialSolution) {
                    return potentialSolution;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    // This is like array.prototype.find, except instead of returning the array element it returns the calculated value
    function findResult(arr, func) {
        for(const i of arr){
            const result = func(i);
            if(result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    function calculateScoreOfCombo(combo) {
        return combo.reduce(
            (totalScore, scoreIndex) => totalScore + scores[scoreIndex],
            0
        );
    }
}


Tail recursion is possible when the last thing you do is a recursive call. But in your case, you do more iterating after the recursive call, so tail recursion does not apply. You can try transforming the code to be tail recursive but it will be a significant redesign.

could you supply a short concrete numeric pseudocode example of some input and its intended output? again, in some easy-to-read pseudocode. thanks.

if you want an answer please supply a short concrete numeric pseudocode example of some input and its intended output. again, in some easy-to-read pseudocode. thanks.

Without the specifics, the  general answer is, by using a "to-do" list/stack.
